# Moving substrings within string

Tags: string, text, awk, sed

Assume a long string that contains multiple fields of information (substrings), each enclosed in square brackets. A few characters preceding each of these fields is a colon character.

The goal is to move all fields enclosed in square brackets (plus the brackets) to their immediately preceding colon character.

```
$echo "foo: bar [baz] qux: quux [quix]" | sought_command
foo[baz]: bar qux[quix]: quux
```

I believe that only *awk* is powerful enough to achieve this, but maybe *sed* can get this done too.

**Note**:

Here's a first attempt using *sed*:

```
echo "foo: bar [baz] qux: quux [quix]" | sed 's/\[*]\/\:\1\2/g'
```

Here's a first attempt using *awk*:

```
echo "foo: bar [baz] qux: quux [quix]" | awk -v 'RS=\]' '{print substr($1,1,length($1)-1) $3 "]: " $2}'
```

Comment: @kvantour Thanks for reminding me, but I wasn't finished with editing my post just yet.

Comment: @tripleee The goal is to move all occurrences of `[any string]` prior to their immediately preceding colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sed:**

```
sed 's|\([^ :]*\):\([^:[]*\)\(\[[^]]*\]\)|\1\3:\2|g'
```

This essentially creates 3 groups:

1. `\([^ :]*\):` anything that does not contain a colon and ends with a colon
2. `\([^:[]*\)` anything that does not contain a colon and an open bracket. Remark, you have to write the colon before the left-square-bracket as `[:]` has an undefined meaning in sed.
3. `\(\[[^]]*\]\)` anything between square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/:([^[]*)([^]]*\]) ?/\2:\1/g' file
```

Pattern match on the symbols following a `:` and rearrange the back references.

The same solution without the syntactic sugar  of the `-r` option:

```
sed 's/:\([^[]*\)\([^]]*\]\) \?/\2:\1/g' file
```